# SQL delete rows which have duplicate values for more than one column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with many columns and I want to delete the rows which have duplicate values for 7 columns and keep only the row which has the highest value on one of the other columns. My table looks like this:

[image]

I need to look at columns: minA, minB, minC, minD, minE, minF, minG and minH and where values are duplicates, I want to keep the row which has the highest "maxPercent".
Based on this, in my table I want to delete everything except for id 1 and id 5. id 2,3 and 4 are duplicates of 1 and 6 and 7 are duplicates for 5.
I have tried the below query for grouping the duplicate rows, but it did not get me the expected result:

```
select * from duplicates t1 where exists (select 1 from duplicates t2 " +
            "       where t1.minA = t2.minA and t1.minB = t2.minB and t1.minC = t2.minC and t1.minD = t2.minD and " +
            "t1.minE = t2.minE and t1.minF = t2.minF and t1.minG = t2.minG and t1.minH = t2.minH and t1.id <> t2.id)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Don't start with a table like this

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the row_number function, the query looks like this:

```
delete from duplicates where id not in (
  select id from (
    select
      id,
      row_number() over(
        partition by minA, minB, minC, minD, minE, minF, minG, minH
        order by maxPercent desc) n
    from duplicates
  ) d
  where n=1
)
```

`n` is in descending order, so `n=1` means each row with the maximum value.

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/stf7y8xXU3spkqrWUB6vuL/0)